# QT 4 packages create dependency problems

Tags: apt, dpkg, qt

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I recently performed an upgrade for my system. Now, when I try to install a package (aptitude for example), I see this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
aptitude is already the newest version.
aptitude set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libqt4-dbus : Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
           Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: qdbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4)
           Breaks: libqt4-dbus:i386 (!= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
libqt4-dbus:i386 : Breaks: libqt4-dbus (!= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
libqt4-network : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
libqt4-script : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
qdbus : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I then proceeded to run `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix the dependency problem. When I ran that, I received this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqt4-dbus
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libqt4-dbus
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/179 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y

dpkg: error processing libqt4-dbus (--configure):
 libqt4-dbus:amd64 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 cannot be configured because libqt4-dbus:i386 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1)

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qdbus:
 qdbus depends on libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:

  Version of libqt4-dbus on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.
dpkg: error processing qdbus (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing libqt4-dbus:i386 (--configure):

 libqt4-dbus:i386 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 cannot be configured because libqt4-dbus:amd64 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4)

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-network:i386:

 libqt4-network:i386 depends on libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:

  Package libqt4-dbus:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-network:i386 (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-network:
 libqt4-network depends on libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:

  Version of libqt4-dbus on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-network (--configure):

 dependencNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
y problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-script:i386:

 libqt4-script:i386 depends on libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-dbus:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-script:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-script:
 libqt4-script depends on libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Version of libqt4-dbus on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-script (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386:
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-network:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-xmlpatternNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                            s:
 libqt4-xmlpatterns depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-network is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-xmlpatterns (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-declarative:i386:
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:

  Package libqt4-network:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-script:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubun
tu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-declarative:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-declarative:
 libqt4-declarative depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-network is No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
       not configured yet.
 libqt4-declarative depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-script is not configured yet.

 libqt4-declarative depends on libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-xmlpatterns is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-declarative (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:
 libqt4-designer depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-script is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:i386:
 libqt4-designer:i386 depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-script:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer:i386 (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-help:
 libqt4-help depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-network is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-help (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-qt3support:i386:
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-designer:i386 is not configured yet.

 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-network:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-qt3support:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-script is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:i386:

 libqt4-scripttools:i386 depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-script:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:i386:
 libqtgui4:i386 depends on libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-declarative:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqtgui4:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:
 libqtgui4 depends on libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-declarative is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqtgui4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libqt4-opengl depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:i386:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libqt4-opengl:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-svg:
 libqt4-svg depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-svg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-svg:i386:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libqt4-svg:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-svg:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-dbus
 qdbus
 libqt4-dbus:i386
 libqt4-network:i386
 libqt4-network
 libqt4-script:i386
 libqt4-script
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386
 libqt4-xmlpatterns
 libqt4-declarative:i386
 libqt4-declarative
 libqt4-designer
 libqt4-designer:i386
 libqt4-help
 libqt4-qt3support:i386
 libqt4-scripttools
 libqt4-scripttools:i386
 libqtgui4:i386
 libqtgui4
 libqt4-opengl
 libqt4-opengl:i386
 libqt4-svg
 libqt4-svg:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` produces very similar results.
Does anyone know how I can resolve these errors? I am currently unable to install any packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by removing the **ubuntu-desktop** package as well as unity-2d and all of the **qt** packages. Then, I reinstalled everything. Now, I can install packages without any trouble.

Comment: in the future aptitude might give you a solutoon not provided via apt-get / dpkg

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had to remove many QT packages, purge them, then do a dist-upgrade:

```
dpkg -r --force-all \
 indicator-appmenu \
 libdconf-dbus-1-0 \
 libdconf-qt0 \
 libqt4-dbus \
 libqt4-declarative \
 libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel \
 libqt4-declarative-gestures \
 libqt4-declarative-particles \
 libqt4-declarative-shaders \
 libqt4-designer \
 libqt4-dev \
 libqt4-opengl-dev \
 libqt4-script \
 libqt4-scripttools \
 libqtbamf1 \
 libqtcore4 \
 libqtdee2 \
 libqtgconf1 \
 libqtgui4 \
 libunity-2d-private0 \
 qt4-dev-tools \
 qt4-doc \
 qt4-qmlviewer \
 qt4-qtconfig \
 ubuntu-desktop \
 unity-2d \
 unity-2d-panel \
 unity-2d-shell \
 unity-2d-spread \
 unixodbc-dev

dpkg --purge \
 indicator-appmenu \
 libdconf-dbus-1-0 \
 libdconf-qt0 \
 libqt4-dbus \
 libqt4-declarative \
 libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel \
 libqt4-declarative-gestures \
 libqt4-declarative-particles \
 libqt4-declarative-shaders \
 libqt4-designer \
 libqt4-dev \
 libqt4-opengl-dev \
 libqt4-script \
 libqt4-scripttools \
 libqtbamf1 \
 libqtcore4 \
 libqtdee2 \
 libqtgconf1 \
 libqtgui4 \
 libunity-2d-private0 \
 qt4-dev-tools \
 qt4-doc \
 qt4-qmlviewer \
 qt4-qtconfig \
 ubuntu-desktop \
 unity-2d \
 unity-2d-panel \
 unity-2d-shell \
 unity-2d-spread \
 unixodbc-dev

apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

Comment: trying it now, let's hope it works